# iPhone X and bottom safe area inset

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, iphone-x

I am working on layout for iPhoneX and have an issue with action sheets and Safari browser. This is an extra space. I need that my action sheets display more at the bottom ? How can I do that? I guess I need to disable safe area but how can I do it?

The reason why it happens probably that I use 2 UIWindows: one for all content and the second to display banner at the bottom of the screen.

the space that is outlined - is something to hide my app from everyone :) It does not exist in the app!

I want the action sheet be closer to the bottom. It works well on all devices except iPhoneX. I have 2 UIWindows (one for all content and the second one for ad at the bottom). So, for iPhoneX the content window has probably some safe area inset and becaise of that action sheet shows not from the bottom edge

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to disable the Safe Areas for the View Controller. They are still useful for the top, trailing and leading edges.

To remove the grey bar all you need is to set the `bottomAnchor` or your containing view to your `superView` instead of the `bottom safe area` with a constant of what you need.

You can also further adjust safe area insets with `additionalSafeAreaInsets`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2902284-additionalsafeareainsets That allows you to leave them as is for the edges that you don't want to modify.

Comment: "To remove the black bar " what? I need to shift action sheet to the bottom al ittle bit

Comment: I mistyped, the grey one I mean.

Comment: no, it is not something that I need to remove, the action sheet should start from grey view

Comment: Oh I see so you want to have the space that is outlined in pink removed and the action sheet be closer to the bottom?

Comment: the space that is outlined - is something to hide my app from everyone :) It does not exist in the app!
 
Yes, I want the action sheet be closer to the bottom. It works well on all devices except iPhoneX. I have 2 UIWindows (one for all content and the second one for ad at the bottom). So, for iPhoneX the content window has probably some safe area inset and becaise of that action sheet shows not from the bottom edge,